# My function doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript

Write the JavaScript code that will loop through an array of integers named cars and test each element of the array to see if it is greater than 10. If it is, display an alert box. The array length is not known to you, but your code must test each element of the array regardless of the array length. You do not have to declare the array or write code to put values into the array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>



<script>
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById(cars[i]) > 10)
    alert("I am an alert box!");

}

var cars = [ 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";


myFunction();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;



}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

can someone point out what im doing wrong.

Comment: This question looks like a school assignment.

Comment: Do you want an alert box for each car that is greater than ten, or an alert box if every car in the list in greater than 10?

Comment: found the answer myself  if `(document.getElementById(cars[i]) > 10)` was the mistake was meant to be if `(cars[i] > 10)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have so much code, just loop through each item and compare it to ten..

```
var cars = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  if (cars[i] > 10) {
    alert(cars[i] + " is greater than 10");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Went complete stupid mode

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>



<script>
function myFunction() {
if (cars[i] > 10) //<-----was if (document.getElementById(cars[i]) > 10)
    alert("I am an alert box!");

}

var cars = [ 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    text += cars[i] + "<br>";


myFunction();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;



}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off just using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
var cars = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

if (cars.every(x => x > 10))
  alert('Every car is greater than 10.');
else alert('False. Every car is not greater than 10.');
// you can remove the else statement; just showing you that it works.
```